# Python Regular Expression Extracting 'name= ....'

Tags: python, regex, extract

I'm using a Python script to read data from our corporate instance of JIRA. There is a value that is returned as a string and I need to figure out how to extract one bit of info from it. What I need is the **'name= ....'** and I just need the numbers from that result.

```
<class 'list'>: ['com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@6f68eefa[id=30943,rapidViewId=10468,state=CLOSED,name=2016.2.4 - XXXXXXXXXX,startDate=2016-05-26T08:50:57.273-07:00,endDate=2016-06-08T20:59:00.000-07:00,completeDate=2016-06-09T07:34:41.899-07:00,sequence=30943]']
```

I just need the ***2016.2.4*** portion of it. This number will not always be the same either.

Any thoughts as how to do this with RE? I'm new to regular expressions and would appreciate any help.

Comment: *"I'm new to regular expressions"* - https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple regular expression can do the trick: `name=([0-9.]+)`.

The primary part of the regex is `([0-9.]+)` which will search for any digit (`0-9`) or period (`.`) in succession (`+`).

Now, to use this:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('name=([0-9.]+)')

string = '''<class 'list'>: ['com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@6f68eefa[id=30943,rapidViewId=10468,state=CLOSED,name=2016.2.4 - XXXXXXXXXX,startDate=2016-05-26T08:50:57.273-07:00,endDate=2016-06-08T20:59:00.000-07:00,completeDate=2016-06-09T07:34:41.899-07:00,sequence=30943]']'''

matches = pattern.search(string)
# Only assign the value if a match is found
name_value = '' if not matches else matches.group(1)
```

Comment: Will try after I'm done getting my crown at the dentist. Seems easy enough though.

Comment: When I use this code in my python file, it gives me an error:

`IndexError: no such group`

Answer (score 0):

Use a [capturing group](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping) to extract the version name:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@6f68eefa[id=30943,rapidViewId=10468,state=CLOSED,name=2016.2.4 - XXXXXXXXXX,startDate=2016-05-26T08:50:57.273-07:00,endDate=2016-06-08T20:59:00.000-07:00,completeDate=2016-06-09T07:34:41.899-07:00,sequence=30943]'
>>> re.search(r"name=([0-9.]+)", s).group(1)
'2016.2.4'
```

where `([0-9.]+)` is a capturing group matching one or more digits or dots, parenthesis define a capturing group.

A non-regex option would involve some [splitting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) by `,`, `=` and `-`:

```
>>> l = [item.split("=") for item in s.split(",")]
>>> next(value[1] for value in l if value[0] == "name").split(" - ")[0]
'2016.2.4'
```

This, of course, needs testing and error handling.

Comment: Will try after I'm done getting my crown at the dentist. Seems easy enough though.

Comment: This works fine in the shell. But, when I use something similar in the file, I get a _no such group_ error: